# Floating point calculations debugging

Tags: python, algorithm, floating-point, differential-equations

So I recently decided to learn python and as a exercise (plus making something useful) I decided to make a Euler's Modified Method algorithm for solving higher-then-first order differential equations. An example input would be:

`python script_name.py -y[0] [10,0]`

where the first argument is the deferential equation (here: y''=-y), and the second one the initial conditions (here: y(0)=10, y'(0)=0). It is then meant to out put the resusts to two files (x-data.txt, and y-data.txt).

Heres the problem:
When in run the code with the specified the final line (at t=1) reads -0.0, but if you solve the ODE (y=10*cos(x)), it should read 5.4. Even if you go through the program with a pen and paper and execute the code, your (and the computers) results apart to diverge by the second iteration). Any idea what could have caused this?

*NB*: I'm using python 2.7 on a os x

Here's my code:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
# A higher order differential equation solver using Euler's Modified Method

import math
import sys

step_size = 0.01
x=0
x_max=1

def derivative(x, y):
    d = eval(sys.argv[1])
    return d

y=eval(sys.argv[2])
order = len(y)
y_derivative=y

xfile = open('x-data.txt','w+')
yfile = open('y-data.txt','w+')

while (x<x_max):
    xfile.write(str(x)+"\n")
    yfile.write(str(y[0])+"\n")

    for i in range(order-1):
        y_derivative[i]=y[(i+1)]
    y_derivative[(order-1)] =  derivative(x,y)

    for i in range(order):
        y[i]=y[i]+step_size*y_derivative[i]
    x=x+step_size


xfile.close()
yfile.close()

print('done')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say `y_derivative=y` they are the SAME list with different names. I.e. when you change `y_derivative[i]=y[i+1]` both lists are changing. You want to use `y_derivative=y[:]` to make a copy of `y` to put in `y_derivative`

See [How to clone or copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-a-list-in-python) for more info

Also see http://effbot.org/zone/python-list.htm

Note, I was able to debug this in IDLE by replacing `sys.argv` with your provided example. Then if you turn on the debugger and step through the code, you can see both lists change.

Comment: Why does y_derivative and y refer to the same list?

If we try it with variables (in used ; instead of newlines):
    a=5;
    b=a;
    print(a,b) # 5 5;
    a=6;
    print(a,b) # 6 5;

Comment: Variables and lists are wholly different entities, I added another link to the answer that can explain more on lists